# Encriptar parametros de URL Laravel y recibirlos con Angular

Tags: php, laravel, angular

Buen día, estoy enviando un correo con laravel para confirmar una participación en un webinar.

```
    public function __construct($user, $primeraRespuesta,$id)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->primeraRespuesta  = $primeraRespuesta;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->datos = ['email' => bcrypt($this->user), 'formulario_id' => bcrypt($this->id)];
    }
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('Email.participationEmailConfirmation')->with(['correo' => $this->user,
                                                                             'respuesta' => $this->primeraRespuesta, 'datos' =>$this->datos]);
    }
```

Y el boton de la vista se ve así

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://localhost:4200/first-confirmation?email={{$datos['email']}}&formulario_id={{$datos['formulario_id']}}" >
    Confirmar participación</a>
```

En angular lo recibo así

```
   this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
     param =>  {this.participante.correo=param ['email'],this.participante.formulario_id = param ['formulario_id']});
```

Pero al volverlo a enviar a laravel para hacer la confirmación, me aparece esto si lo quiero desencriptar para hacer una modificación en la base de datos

```
exception: "Illuminate\\Contracts\\Encryption\\DecryptException"
file: "C:\\laragon\\www\\formularios_seven_backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\Encrypter.php"
line: 196
message: "The payload is invalid."
trace: (42) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo es que envías un correo en Laravel y lo recibes en Angular?

Comment: no, envio un correo con laravel que tiene un boton que te lleva a la url de confirmación de angular

Comment: puedes colocar una url con la info en base64

Comment: Eso hice Steven y funcionó gracias, sabes si por casualidad eso afectaría algun correo con "ñ"? de igual manera gracias amigo.